# Teradata JDBC 16.20 returns wrong date in Datagrip

Tags: sql, teradata, datagrip, teradata-sql-assistant

I am using Teradata JDBC 16.20 in Datagrip.
Whenever I try to do anything with date, it returns 1 day less.
For instance: `SELECT date'2017-08-01'` returns `2017-07-31` in Datagrip and in Teradata SQL Assistant it returns correctly `01/08/2017`.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: If it helps, this must be a Datagrip issue. I just ran `SELECT date'2017-08-01'` through JDBC 16.20 Driver against my 15.10 database and it returned as expected.

Comment: Might be based on different Time Zones. `SELECT CAST (date'2017-08-01' AS TIMESTAMP AT LOCAL), CAST (date'2017-08-01' AS TIMESTAMP AT 0)`

Comment: @dnoeth that seems to work. thanks very much

Comment: @dnoeth: If I CAST date as TIMESTAMP, it works well but if I just return DATE or CAST TIMESTAMP as DATE, it returns 1 day less.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue using DataGrip with a Vertica database.  My hunch is that the date is being shifted twice.  When I select current_timestamp (which on Vertica is timestamp with timezone) the date is correct (typically one day earlier than the current date), but when I select current_date, I get the previous day (my timezone is US/Pacific).  What I think is happening is the JDBC driver is adjusting the date based on the two timezones, and then DataGrip is then adjusting it a second time.

We don't have issues using the same Vertica database with the same JDBC driver, but a different SQL Client (DbVisualizer).

The only workaround I can offer using DataGrip is to install a much older version.  DataGrip 2016.3.4, Build #DB-163.13906.13, built on February 21, 2017 seems to handle date columns correctly.

Comment: This is why I haven't upgraded from 2017.2.2. My new coworker downloaded a newer version and has to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to VM options seems to solve the problem.