# MySQL str_to_date returning the date minus one day in Datagrip

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I appologize if I'm missing something, I've never encountered this, though.

I noticed my query was returning the wrong date, I was passing `'2019-07-19'` and it was giving me the result set for `'2019-07-18'`

Now I see this output:

```sql
select str_to_date('2019-07-19', '%Y-%m-%d');

1| '2019-07-18'
```

Can anyone explain why that's happening? This isn't my database so I haven't configured any settings.

I'm using datagrip to execute the above query which gives the strange answer.

When I execute through the cli I get the correct return.

running

```sql
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone, @@system_time_zone, TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);

1| SYSTEM    | SYSTEM    | UTC   | 00:00:00
```

in both environments shows the same thing

I also see that explitly stating the timestamp seems to return the correct response as well

```sql
select str_to_date('2019-07-19 0:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

1| '2019-07-19 00:00:00'
```

So it seems that datagrip is doing something wrong...

Comment: cannot reproduce.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635645/teradata-jdbc-16-20-returns-wrong-date-in-datagrip One of the answers: Adding `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to VM options seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the corresponding time zone in the connection properties.
[image]

Comment: both this and setting `Duser.timzone=UTC` worked for me, thanks!